# Auto adjusting views based on dynamic child components in react native

Tags: dynamic, flexbox, react-native, react-native-ios

I'm trying to create a view like below,
[image]

The checkbox list is dynamic and may increase or decrease. At the moment for the purpose of the screenshot I've added fixed height and width for both my checkboxContainer and checkBoxTextContainer style. But I need the same to work without specifying fixed height and width. Below is my current code.

```
render() {
    return(
        <ScrollView
            style={{flex:1}}>
<KeyboardAwareScrollView
        contentContainerStyle={styles.imageContainer}
        resetScrollToCoords={{ x: 0, y: 0 }}
        scrollEnabled={true}
        keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled"
      >
<View style={styles.dynamicData}>{this.renderData()}</View>
</KeyboardAwareScrollView>
</ScrollView>
    );
}



renderData(){
    //some other code to display other fields
    if (item === "-checkBox-") {
        return (
          <CheckBoxInput
            checkBoxContainerStyle={styles.checkBoxContainer}
            checkBoxTextContainerStyle={styles.checkBoxTextContainer}
            checkboxStyle={styles.checkBoxStyle}
            rightTextMarginStyle={styles.rightTextMargin}
            questionTextStyle={styles.questionText}
            checkBoxes={this.getDropDownValue(i)}
            checkBoxCheckedImage={Images.checkBoxTick}
            checkBoxUnCheckedImage={Images.checkBoxEmpty}
            updateDropDown={this.onOptionChanged}
            index={i}
            key={index}
          />
        );
      }
}
```

This is my CheckBoxInputComponent

```
export default class CheckBoxInput extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  //Handle checkbox change
  handleCheckBoxChange = event => {
    console.log("Selected Checkbox = " + event.value);
    this.props.updateDropDown(this.props.index, event.value, "checkBox");
  };

  //Renders checkbox view
  renderCheckBoxView() {
    let checkBoxComponentList = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < this.props.checkBoxes.length; i++) {
      checkBoxComponentList.push(
        <View
          style={this.props.checkBoxTextContainerStyle}
          key={this.props.checkBoxes[i].id}
        >
          <CheckBox
            style={this.props.checkboxStyle}
            onClick={this.handleCheckBoxChange.bind(
              this,
              this.props.checkBoxes[i]
            )}
            isChecked={this.props.checkBoxes[i].isChecked}
            checkedImage={<Image source={this.props.checkBoxCheckedImage} />}
            unCheckedImage={
              <Image source={this.props.checkBoxUnCheckedImage} />
            }
          />
          <View style={this.props.rightTextMarginStyle} />
          <Text style={this.props.questionTextStyle} numberOfLines={1}>
            {this.props.checkBoxes[i].value}
          </Text>
        </View>
      );
    }
    return (
      <View style={this.props.checkBoxContainerStyle}>
        {checkBoxComponentList}
      </View>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return this.renderCheckBoxView();
  }
}
```

These are the styles

```
dynamicData: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "row",
    flexWrap: "wrap",
    alignItems: "center"
  },

checkBoxTextContainer: {
    // width:150
    flex: 1,
    height: 45,
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "flex-start",
    alignItems: "center"
  },
  rightTextMargin: {
    width: 15,
    height: 45
  },
  checkBoxContainer: {
    // width: "100%",
    // height: 200,
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "row",
    flexWrap: "wrap"
  },
  checkBoxStyle: {
    width: 20,
    height: 20
  },
 imageContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "flex-start",
    alignItems: "flex-start"
  },
  questionText: {
    color: "black",
    textAlign: "left",
    fontSize: 16,
    fontFamily: "SegoeUI-Semibold",
    lineHeight: 30
  }
```

Right now it doesn't display the checkbox section. Its now like this
[image]

Any help is really appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix it by modifying my checkBoxTextContainer and checkBoxContainer style. The problem was that I was adding `flex:1` constraint which I thought would auto adjust the width and height but it actually set it to fill based on the superview so if you remove that then it will automatically adjust based on the content.

```
checkBoxTextContainer: {
    height: 45,
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "flex-start",
    alignItems: "center"
  },

checkBoxContainer: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    flexWrap: "wrap"
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the height and the width of the view you can use the onLayout function which will be called when the view is mounted and whenever the orientation changes, if you use the onLayout function of the parent view you can get the currently rendered height and width of the view which you can use in your styles you will have to update the state to re render with the new height and width.

Documentation for onLayout
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view#onlayout

Sample code to access the height width details from onLayout

```
onLayout = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      width: e.nativeEvent.layout.width,
      height: e.nativeEvent.layout.height,
      x: e.nativeEvent.layout.x,
      y: e.nativeEvent.layout.y
    })
  }
```